# BufferOverflowException when trying to encode data

Tags: java, android, buffer-overflow

I try create encoder for "audio/3gpp" and my app crash.

I configurate MediaCodec...

```
    String mMime = "audio/3gpp";
    mMediaCodec = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType(mMime);
    MediaFormat mMediaFormat = MediaFormat.createAudioFormat(mMime, 44100, 1);
    mMediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, 12000);
    mMediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_SAMPLE_RATE, 44100);
    mMediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_CHANNEL_COUNT, 1);
    mMediaCodec.configure(mMediaFormat, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
    mMediaCodec.start();
```

And then I trying to encode data...

```
private byte[] EncodeDataTo3gp(byte[] input)
{
    byte[] outData = null;

    try 
    {
        ByteBuffer[] inputBuffers = mMediaCodec.getInputBuffers();

        ByteBuffer[] outputBuffers = mMediaCodec.getOutputBuffers();
        int inputBufferIndex = mMediaCodec.dequeueInputBuffer(-1);
        if (inputBufferIndex >= 0) 
        {
            ByteBuffer inputBuffer = inputBuffers[inputBufferIndex];
            inputBuffer.clear();
            inputBuffer.put(input);
            mMediaCodec.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex, 0, input.length, 0, 0);
        }

        MediaCodec.BufferInfo bufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
        int outputBufferIndex = mMediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, 0);
        while (outputBufferIndex >= 0) 
        {
            ByteBuffer outputBuffer = outputBuffers[outputBufferIndex];
            outData = new byte[bufferInfo.size];
            outputBuffer.get(outData);

            mMediaCodec.releaseOutputBuffer(outputBufferIndex, false);
            outputBufferIndex = mMediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, 0);
        }
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }

    return outData;
}
```

But this function is throwing an exception. when `"inputBuffer.put(input);": java.nio.BufferOverflowException`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to add `MediaFormat.KEY_MAX_INPUT_SIZE` parameter to your `mMediaFormat` according to `input` size. It will increase capacity of `inputBuffers`.

Answer (score 2):

The input buffer handling looks okay -- you're using `clear()` to reset the position and limit -- so I'm assuming that the input you're providing is simply larger than the buffer can hold.  If `input.length` is larger than `inputBuffer.limit()`, you'll need to provide it in smaller chunks.

The output buffer management looks a little strange -- you're re-allocating `outData` on each loop iteration, so if you get more than one buffer out you'll end up discarding all but the last one.

For both input and output, you're not handling negative return values.  In particular, `INFO_*_BUFFERS_CHANGED` requires you to re-acquire the `ByteBuffer` array.

Answer (score 1):

Put `inputBuffer.rewind();` before `inputBuffer.put(input);` and try it